# How to correctly use 'connect' in react-redux with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using typescript in an application, but found some problem with react-redux. The 'connect' method reports a problem and I have no idea with it since I'm a rookie with typescript and redux. What should I do or where in my code should be modified? Thanks a lot

Application built with `typescript@3.3`, `react@16.8.5`, `react-redux@7.1.0`.

```js
// article
interface IArticle {
  title: string,
  author: string
}

// state
interface MyState {
  list: [],
  article: IArticle
}

// stateMapToProps
interface MyStateProps {
  article: IArticle
}

// router match
interface MatchParams {
  id: string
}

// own props
interface MyOwnProps extends RouteComponentProps < MatchParams > {
  article: IArticle,
  dispatch: (o: object) => {}
}

class ArticleContainer extends Component < MyOwnProps, {} > {
  constructor(props: MyOwnProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      dispatch
    } = this.props;
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    dispatch(fetchArticle(id))
  }

  render() {
    const {
      article
    } = this.props;
    return ( <
      Article article = {
        article
      } > < /Article>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: MyState): MyStateProps => {
  return {
    article: state.article
  }
}

export default connect < MyStateProps, {}, {
  article: IArticle
} > (
  mapStateToProps
)(ArticleContainer)
```

Here is the code of async action `fetchArticle`

```
function fetchArticle(id: string) {
  return function(dispatch: (action: AnyAction) => {}): Promise<void> {
    dispatch(getArticle(id))

    return axios.get(`/article/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(getArticleSuccess(res.data))
      })
  }
}
```

Error happens at the `export` line and message is as below:

> Argument of type '(state: MyState) => MyStateProps' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam'.   Type '(state: MyState) => MyStateProps' is not
>   assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory'.
>       Types of parameters 'state' and 'initialState' are incompatible.
>         Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MyState': list, articlets(2345)

Comment: Just remove the typing from connect. Connect is already infers typing, from mapStateToProps.
`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleContainer);`

Comment: also, your component should be `Component<MyOwnProps, MyState>`

Comment: recommend checking out the following [resource](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide)

Comment: @eenagy thanks first. I tried and instead the `ArticleContainer` part in `export` line report a message, also the `interface MyState` represents the structure of the store created with redux, not the 'state' of the `Class`, so I think there is no need to put it in the generics. I hope I make myself understandable.

Comment: And the error message for `ArticleContainer` in `connect` part is as below(only record the first sentence since it is too long to write here):
Argument of type 'typeof ArticleContainer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<MyStateProps & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, MyOwnProps>>'......ts(2345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum steps to be able to compile your code:

1. `MyOwnProps` should be

   ```
   import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

   interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
       (dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => MyState): any;
   }

   // As you're going to dispatch thunk actions, dispatch should be overloaded
   interface Dispatch<TAction> {
       (action: AppThunkAction<TAction>): any
       (action: TAction): TAction
   }

   // own props
   interface MyOwnProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
       article: IArticle,
       dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>
   }
   ```
2. If you want to provide types for `connect` function, add `MyState` as last type like so

   ```
   export default connect <MyStateProps, {}, {
           article: IArticle
       }, MyState >(
           mapStateToProps
   )(ArticleContainer)
   ```

   Or you can allow compiler to infer types itself, which is preferred

   ```
   export default connect(
       mapStateToProps
   )(ArticleContainer)
   ```

So working result

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect, ResolveThunks } from 'react-redux';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';

// article
interface IArticle {
    title: string,
    author: string
}

// state
interface MyState {
    list: [],
    article: IArticle
}

// stateMapToProps
interface MyStateProps {
    article: IArticle
}

// router match
interface MatchParams {
    id: string
}

export interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
    (dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => MyState): any;
}

interface Dispatch<TAction> {
    (action: AppThunkAction<TAction>): any
    (action: TAction): TAction
}

// own props
interface MyOwnProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
    article: IArticle,
    dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>
}

function getArticle(id: string) {
    return {
        type: 'GET_ARTICLE',
        id
    }
}

function getArticleSuccess(i: any) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_ARTICLE',
        i
    }
}



const fetchArticle = (id: string): AppThunkAction<AnyAction> =>
    (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(getArticle(id))

        return axios.get(`/article/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(getArticleSuccess(res.data))
            })
    }

class ArticleContainer extends Component<MyOwnProps, {}> {
    constructor(props: MyOwnProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            dispatch
        } = this.props;
        const id = this.props.match.params.id
        dispatch(fetchArticle(id))
    }

    render() {
        const {
            article
        } = this.props;
        return (<div>article: {article}</div>
          )
        }
      }

const mapStateToProps = (state: MyState): MyStateProps => {
  return {
                article: state.article
          }
        }

export default connect(
            mapStateToProps
)(ArticleContainer)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This method solves the error I mentioned, however, the `dispatch(fetchArticle(id))` reports an error, is it because my `fetchArticle` method is a async method and returns a Promise? ps: I supplement `fetchArticle` code in the question.

Comment: I think the error mainly reports the parameter type, but I have no idea how to solve it. Here is the error message:
Argument of type '(dispatch: (action: AnyAction) => {}) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: (action: AnyAction) => {}) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)

Comment: I have already solved the problem based on your method, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry, doesn;t mentionet this. I've updated the answer and typed `dispatch` so it be able to take functions as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, how to type a react file when using redux, based on your example.

```js
// article-container.js file
import { connect, DispatchProp } from "react-redux";
import { Component } from "react";

// import the real RouteComponent, this is just a demo example
interface RouteComponentProps<T> {
  match: { params: T };
}
// article
interface IArticle {
  title: string;
  author: string;
}
// import the real Article, this is just a demo example

const Article = ({ article }: { article: IArticle }) => {
  return <div>{article.title}</div>;
};

// import the real fetchArticle, this is just a demo example

const fetchArticle = (id: string) => {
  return {
    type: "SOME_ACTION",
    payload: {
      id,
    },
  };
};

// state
interface MyState {
  list: [];
  article: IArticle;
}

// stateMapToProps
interface MyStateProps {
  article: IArticle;
}

// router match
interface MatchParams {
  id: string;
}

// own props
interface MyOwnProps {
  article: IArticle;
}
type AllProps = MyOwnProps & RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> & DispatchProp;

class ArticleContainer extends Component<AllProps> {
  constructor(props: AllProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    dispatch(fetchArticle(id));
  }

  render() {
    const { article } = this.props;
    return <Article article={article} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: MyState): MyStateProps => {
  return {
    article: state.article,
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(ArticleContainer);
```

And use it like so

```
import ArticleContainer from "./article-container";

export default () => {
  // this is coming from router, just an example for demonstration
  const match = { params: { id: "23" } };
  return (
    <div>
      <ArticleContainer match={match} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with remove the generics declaration of `connect` method and use `ThunkDispatch` with async action creator. The code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { fetchArticle } from '../store/actions';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import Article from '../components/Article/Article'
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

// article
interface IArticle {
  title: string,
  author: string
}

// state
interface MyState {
  list: [],
  article: IArticle
}

// stateMapToProps
interface StateToProps {
  article: IArticle
}

// router match
interface MatchParams {
  id: string
}

// own props
interface MyOwnProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
  article: IArticle,
  getArticle: (id: string) => Promise<void>
}

class ArticleContainer extends Component<MyOwnProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: MyOwnProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getArticle } = this.props;
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    getArticle(id)
  }

  render() {
    const { article } = this.props;
    return (
      <Article article={article}></Article>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: MyState): StateToProps => {
  return {
    article: state.article
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
  return {
    getArticle: (id: string) => dispatch(fetchArticle(id))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleContainer)
```

Thanks for the help!